# Unable to get sufficient scaling in a boxplot

Tags: r, boxplot, axes

I seem to have a problem with the scaling I didn't find any answer on here.

I created a boxplot with the parameters "HR" = Heartrate and "Phase" = Centrifuge Phase. There are phases 0-9.

This is what I've got so far.

```
boxplot(HR[Gender=="f"]~Phase[Gender=="f"],main="Heart Rate of Females",font.main=2, xlab="Phase", ylab="Heart Rate (beats/min)", axes=FALSE)
axis(side=1,at=c(0, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),labels=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9), xlim=range(0:10), font.lab=4)
axis(side=2,at=c(0, 60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130),labels=c(0, 60,70,80,90,100,110,120,130),las=1, font.lab=4)
```

It all seems fine. However, I cannot seem to solve the problem of letting phase 0 be plotted on a corresponding 0-value on the x-axis.
Instead, I am seeing phase 0 on position 1 of the x-axis, phase 1 on position 2 of the x-axis and so forth until phase 9 is not on the x-axis anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I used data you've provided in another question of yours to reproduce your boxplot code.

```
df <- data.frame(
  Phase = factor(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9)),
  HR = c(67, 70, 70, 73, 82, 83, 104, 106, 73, 86, 74, 65, 86, 82, 94, 108, 73, 81, 67, 68),
  Gender = factor(c("female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male")),
  )
```

Then, I used the subset function in R to create a second data.frame with just "female" observations.

```
df2 = subset(df,df$Gender=="female")
```

Lastly, I used the boxplot function (as you did) from R `graphics` package and all phases were displayed correctly on the x axis.

```
boxplot(HR~Phase, data=df2,
    main="Heart Rate of Females",
    xlab="Phase",
    ylab="Heart Rate (beats/min)",
    ylim=c(60,130),
    par(font.lab=4,font.main=2))
```

There are just horizontal lines in the boxplot, because there is just one observation for each phase.

[image]